Кодировка данных взятых из базы данных?
я реализую простой пример взятия данных из базы данных и вывод их на экран. Возникла проблема с кодировкой. Вместо русских букв отображаются знаки вопроса. Кодировка данных выставлена такая: utf8_unicode_ci. кодировка БД  такая же. Данные в веб-интерфейсе отображаются правильно. А вот при исполнении PHP-файла выводятся знаки вопроса.
БД расположена на сайте infinityfree.com

Как решить эту проблему?

установить кодировку соединения
